# Search Engine Friendly URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been having a look at changing my websites URLs from dynamic to SEO URLs.

My current search url looks like:

```
search.php?q=dvd_player&attr=brand&=attr=price&page=56
```

I have got the following code on my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 NC,L
```

The above code works if I only want to obtain the "q" however I'm not too sure how I can obtain each of the "attr" and "page" variables.

Another issue which comes to this is that the amount of "attr" is dynamic on a product searched, so one product may have only three where another one may have 20.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need QSA flag here. `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**UPDATE:** To rewrite `/search/dvd-player/attr/brand/attr/price/page/2` to `/search.php?q=dvd_player&attr=brand&=attr=price&page=2` use this **recursive rewrite rule**:

```
RewriteRule ^(search)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(search)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: I have `NC,L` which I forgot to add on the question.

Comment: @DainisAbols: `QSA` is needed otherwise original query string will be lost.

Comment: If you enter this URL in browser `/search/dvd_player?attr=brand&=attr=price&page=56` above rule will rewrite to /search.php?q=dvd_player&attr=brand&=attr=price&page=56`

Comment: @anubhava Ah yes that works. What about if i wanted to keep variables seperated like `search/dvd-player/attr/brand/attr/price/page/2`?

Comment: That can be done too, I will update the answer in few minutes.

Comment: @anubhava Without being rude I don't think this works because it gives me a page not found error.

Comment: Test with this URL: `/search/q/dvd-player/attr/brand/attr/price/page/2`

Comment: @anubhava ah that's works, Brilliant. Also is there a limit on the amount of "attr=X" added to the URL? Because I am using this on a search page and there could be loads of these attributes.

Comment: No there is no limit since rule is recursive.